# Pandas - Get last element after str.split()

Tags: python, pandas, split

I use pandas and I have data and the data look like this

```
FirstName LastName StudentID
FirstName2 LastName2 StudentID2
```

Then I split it based on 'space' using `str.split()`

So the data will look like this in DataFrame

```
[[FirstName, LastName, StudentID],
[FirstName2, LastName2, StudentID2]]
```

How to take the StudentID for every students only and save it in new column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting the last element of a list inside a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201830/selecting-the-last-element-of-a-list-inside-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to take the last element of each of the split strings:

```
ids = [val[-1] for val in your_string.split()]
```

Comment: Or you can use
`ids=[val[1] for val in your_string.rsplit(maxsplit=1)]`

It may be faster. :)

Answer (score 36):

Try the below solution:

```
item["x"]["y"].split(' ')[-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would add this simple solution which doesn't use lists or list comprehension to split an existing column/series and store the last item from the split to a new column/series in the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['FirstName LastName StudentID',
'FirstName2 LastName2 StudentID2']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['text'])

df['id'] = df.text.str.split(" ").str.get(-1)
```

**Output:**

index  text                              id

0      FirstName LastName StudentID      StudentID

0      FirstName2 LastName2 StudentID2   StudentID2

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it only uses vectorized operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['FirstName LastName StudentID',
'FirstName2 LastName2 StudentID2']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['text'])

df['id'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
text          id
0     FirstName LastName StudentID   StudentID
1  FirstName2 LastName2 StudentID2  StudentID2
```

Or, as an alternative:

```
df['id'] = [x.split()[-1] for x in df.text]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
text          id
0     FirstName LastName StudentID   StudentID
1  FirstName2 LastName2 StudentID2  StudentID2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data frame constructor

```
pd.DataFrame(df.text.str.split(' ').tolist()).iloc[:,0]
Out[15]: 
0     FirstName
1    FirstName2
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

For OP's particular case, another approach is using `.extract()` and capturing the desired chunk of the string, without creating an intermediate list:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd # 2.0.3
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["aaa bb cc", "xx y zzzz"]})
>>> df["a"].str.extract(r"(\S+)$")
      0
0    cc
1  zzzz
```

The regex `(\S+)$` grabs one or more non-space characters at the end of the string. `(\S+)\s*$` is useful if there is trailing whitespace.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69061998/6243352) shows the intermediate list idea nicely, but you can use an index rather than `.get()`:

```py
>>> df["a"].str.split().str[-1]
0      cc
1    zzzz
Name: a, dtype: object
```

See also [Selecting the last element of a list inside a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201830/selecting-the-last-element-of-a-list-inside-a-pandas-dataframe/67202279#67202279)

Answer (score -2):

Why not try a simple list comprehension

```
students = [
    ["FirstName", "LastName", "StudentID"],
    ["FirstName2", "LastName2", "StudentID2"]
]

print([student[2] for student in students])
```

which will print

```
['StudentID', 'StudentID2']
```